# A plugin for vim to see git diff on specific file

Tags: vim, git

I am working in Vim on a Git project.
Is there a way to see the diff like 'git diff' on a specific file in vim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fugitive plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) is a popular Git plugin for Vim. It offers a `:Gdiff` command to show the differences side-by-side inside Vim, and you can obtain the diff via `:Git! diff`.